# BootStrap 3.3 collapse block radio button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

I have a issue with bootstrap.
When the div is extend the radio button will block and won't work.

Here's the code :

```
<form name="today_task" action="" method="post">
    <div data-toggle="collapse" id="add_task" class="collapse">
        <textarea name="task_content" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Enter task"></textarea>
        <input type="radio" name="priority" value="3"> High Priority <br />
        <input type="radio" name="priority" value="2" checked> Medium Priority <br />
        <input type="radio" name="priority" value="1"> Low Priority <br />
    </div>
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#add_task" href="#add_task"><input type="button" name="submit_new_task" id="add_task_button" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%;" onClick="submit_button()"></a>                                           
</form>
```

Here's the problem : https://jsfiddle.net/g14ajcgh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the "data-toggle=collapse" from

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" id="add_task" class="collapse">
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

how about making another div for your radio button?